# RST hijacking good ACK number

Tags: linux, networking, security, tcp, tcpip

I'm trying to perform a RST hijacking sur on my Virtual Machine. I have 3 Vm's:
-attack : 172.10.10.11
-victim : 172.10.10.21
-pirate : 172.10.10.31

First, I connect from attack with telnet to the port 80 of victim. With tcpdump on victim, I check that I get the 3 way handshake :

> 22:29:20.185032 IP 172.10.10.11.43086 > 172.10.10.21.http: Flags [S],
>   seq 2173271328, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3615590 ecr
>   0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
>
> 22:29:20.185090 IP 172.10.10.21.http > 172.10.10.11.43086: Flags [S.],
>   seq 3246536796, **ack 2173271329**, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS
>   val 3598763 ecr 3615590,nop,wscale 6], length 0
>
> 22:29:20.186088 IP 172.10.10.11.43086 > 172.10.10.21.http: Flags [.],
>   ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 3615590 ecr 3598763], length 0

Then on the spoof VM, I forge a packet with source IP 172.10.10.11 (attack), RST flag set, and I try to put the correct ack number. Here is what i get with tcpdump on victim:

> 22:30:14.872548 IP 172.10.10.11.43086 > 172.10.10.21.http: Flags [R],
>   seq 2173271329, win 8192, length 0

So the packet is not dropped by victim, the RST flag is set, but nothing happens.
Any ideas?